# grails header title not working with layout - sitemesh and layout

Tags: grails, layout, gsp

I have a **base header layout** (**base-header-footer.gsp**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="${g.message(code: 'title.index.page')}"/></title>
    </head>
    ... some common resources loading....
     <body id="launch">
    <g:layoutBody/>
   ...........................
    <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

And then 2 more header, one for logged-in user, and another for guest users, and both of these header layout are extending the base layout.

**Guest users** (**anonymouys-header-footer.gsp**) -

```
<g:applyLayout name="base-header-footer"> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
        ... render guest user header
        <g:layoutBody/>         
    </body>
</html>
```

**Logged-in users** (**loggedin-header-footer.gsp**) -

```
<g:applyLayout name="base-header-footer"> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        ... some css
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
        ... Render header for logged-in user
    </body>
            ... load some JS file...
</html>
```

Now in specific pages I apply guest OR logged-in layout based on user's login state, hence I want to show the page specific title user is on, but it doesn't work.

This is how I am using those layout

**OrderStatus.gsp -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Order status | Some title</title>
        <meta name="layout" content="logged-in-header-footer" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'some.js')}"></script>
       </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

But I still see the title which is defined **base-header-footer.gsp**, **not the one in OrderStatus.gsp**

I have also tried using **g:layoutTitle** in **OrderStatus.gsp** but doesn't help.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<meta name="layout" content="base-header-footer">
```

in your pages to load the layout, then add your title there,

```
<title>${whatever.something()}</title>
```

in your layout add this:

```
<title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
<title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
```

in your layouts (**base-header-footer** and **loggedin-header-footer.gsp**). More info in the [official documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/layoutTitle.html).

Comment: I want to render page specific title, but it's rendering the layout title. If you see I am already using <g:layoutTitle/> in base-header-footer, and use a title tag in decorated page.                 Please make a note that I am using <g:applyLayout> to extend base layout and I believe that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, you use g:layoutTitle in top level layout, but don't use it in middle layout. put g:layoutTitle in loggedin-header-footer.gsp